# Perl regex capture groups

Tags: regex, shell, perl

I use perl regex capture groups to replace the pattern of a large number of files.

File example 1:

```
title="alpha" lorem ipsum lorem ipsum name="beta"
```

File example 2:

```
title="omega" Morbi posuere metus purus name="delta"
```

for

```
title="beta" lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
```

```
title="delta" Morbi posuere metus purus
```

using

```
find . -type f -exec perl -pi -w -e 's/title="(?'one'.*?)"(?'three'.*?)name="(?'two'.*?)"/title="\g{two}"\g{three}/g;' \{\} \;
```

(Note that (1) attribute values of title and name are unknown variables and (2) the content between `title="alpha"` and `name="beta"` differs. )

I am still learning perl regex. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It looks to me like your Perl regex may be fine, but you're making life (more) difficult for yourself because you're mixing it up with shell quoting. The `'` around the code is interrupted by the `'` symbols around your `(?'identifier'pattern')` bits. Try using `(?<identifier>pattern)` instead, like this? `s/title="(?<one>.*?)"(?<three>.*?)name="(?<two>.*?)"/title="\g{two}"\g{three}/g;`

Answer (score 1):

Your challenge is the shell quoting, but also the user of named capture groups. I'm not quite clear on whether you can use those the way you do, in the substitution.

This works to accomplish your task, as I understand it:

```shell
find . -type f -exec perl -pi -w -e 's/title="(.*?)"(.*?)name="(.*?)"/title="$3"$2/g;' \{\} \;
```

For instance:

```
$ cat file1
title="alpha" lorem ipsum lorem ipsum name="beta"

$ cat file2
title="omega" Morbi posuere metus purus name="delta"
```

Run the above line, and then:

```
$ cat file1
title="beta" lorem ipsum lorem ipsum

$ cat file2
title="delta" Morbi posuere metus purus
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: This is a good answer and the `shell` tag should be on this question. I rejected that but was wrong in doing so.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73168776/19301214 -- I think this is an even better answer, on the copied/duplicated question.